# Replacing only first occurrence of characters in list items in python?

Tags: python, string, list, replace

It's pretty hard to explain but here's my issue..

```
sampleList = ['_ This is an item.','__ This is also an item']
```

I'm trying to take sampleList and find if `_` occurs ONLY in the first character line, replace it with `#`, and then if `__` occurs, replace with `&`.

It's a bit hard to understand even for myself.

Basically if I have a list, I want it to work through the list, only find the FIRST instance of a possible dict and replace it with the corresponding value. And then return that entire list..

EDIT:

Sorry if I wasn't descriptive enough..

```
dictarray = {
'_':'&',
'__':'*#',
'____':'*$(@'
}

sampleList = ['_ This is an item.','__ This is also an item','_ just another _ item','____ and this last one']
```

output:

```
sampleList = ['& This is an item.','*# This is also an item','& just another _ item','*$(@ and this last one']
```

I need to be able to capture if the key is found at the beginning of the item, if so, change it out for the value.

Comment: We need to see the other structure as well.

Comment: Can you give a few examples of expected return-values for various values of `sampleList`?

Comment: There you guys go, does that help any?

Comment: Do you always want to replace the first, or only the first *if* the line starts with it?  E.g. should "Not quite _" stay "Not quite _" or become "Not quite &"?

Comment: It should stay as '`Not quite _`'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# The original input data
dictarray = {
'_':'&',
'__':'*#',
'____':'*$(@'
}

sampleList = ['_ This is an item.','__ This is also an item','_ just another _ item','____ and this last one']

# Order the substitutions so the longest are first.
subs = sorted(dictarray.items(), key=lambda pair: len(pair[0]), reverse=True)

def replace_first(s, subs):
    """Replace the prefix of `s` that first appears in `subs`."""
    for old, new in subs:
        if s.startswith(old):
            # replace takes a count of the number of replacements to do.
            return s.replace(old, new, 1)
    return s

# make a new list by replace_first'ing all the strings.
new_list = [replace_first(s, subs) for s in sampleList]

print new_list
```

produces:

```
['& This is an item.', '*# This is also an item', '& just another _ item', '*$(@ and this last one']
```

Here I've massaged the dictarray to order the substitution longest first, so that shorter prefixes don't preclude longer ones.

Comment: "One obvious way to do it", I guess: my line was `d_sorted = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: len(kv[0]), reverse=True)`. :^)

Comment: @DSM: if only there was one obvious way to name all the variables! :)

Comment: Perfect! Wow, this place is unbelievable. Now I do just want to add one thing though.. I'm going to have instances in the list where an item will need to have ALL of the keys replaced. So if `%%%` appears twelve times in an item, it needs to be replaced all twelve times. But this rule would only apply to specific keys. Is this even possible?

Comment: Took me a second to see it, but this is a very elegant solution.  +1, 'one obvious way to do it' indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Here the trick is to place the longer underscores(`__`) in `if` condition and then the smaller ones(`_`) in `elif` conditions:

```
dic = {
'_':'&',
'__':'*#',
'____':'*$(@'
}
lis=['_ This is an item.','__ This is also an item','_ just another _ item','____ and this last one']
for x in sorted(dic,key=len,reverse=True):
    for i,y in enumerate(lis):
        if y.startswith(x):
            lis[i]=y.replace(x,dic[x])

print(lis)
```

**output:**

```
['& This is an item.', '*# This is also an item', '& just another & item', '*$(@ and this last one']
```

Comment: Hardcoding everything doesn't seem very robust.

Comment: @DSM the OP didn't mentioned the dict in the original question, so that's why i used hardcoded `if` and `elif`.

Comment: Actually, the OP did -- "only find the FIRST instance of a *possible dict*" -- but even if he hadn't, hardcoding each line would still have been a bad idea, because it made the code depend upon the values.